# Shell script work on terminal, not when it has run by cronjob

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu

i'm facing a strange situation and i searched and haven't found anything. I have a bash script that take a date and add 72 hours to it. There is no problem when i run it from terminal but when it runs by cronjob it gaves me an error:

```
if [ $# -eq 3 ] ; then

# ----------
# PARAMETERS
# ----------
start_YYYYMMDDHH=${1}
ini_YYYYMMDDHH=${2}
flen=${3}
ini_HH=${ini_YYYYMMDDHH:8:2}
start_YYYY=${start_YYYYMMDDHH:0:4}
start_MM=${start_YYYYMMDDHH:4:2}
start_DD=${start_YYYYMMDDHH:6:2}
start_HH=${start_YYYYMMDDHH:8:2}
start_II=00
start_SS=00
end_YYYYMMDDHH=`date --utc +%Y%m%d%H%i%s -d "${start_YYYY}-${start_MM}-${start_DD} ${start_HH}:${start_II}:${start_SS} UTC +${flen} hours"`
end_YYYYMMDDHH=${end_YYYYMMDDHH:0:10}
end_YYYY=${end_YYYYMMDDHH:0:4}
end_MM=${end_YYYYMMDDHH:4:2}
end_DD=${end_YYYYMMDDHH:6:2}
end_HH=${end_YYYYMMDDHH:8:2}
end_II=00
end_SS=00
```

and when i run it by cron it gaves me this error:

> date: extra operand ‘-d’
>   Try 'date --help' for more information.

do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I tried adding it in the crontab file, works fine for me.

Comment: @saisasanka the weird thing is that it works in another machine also and i tested !!!! any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: Does the machine which is not working have another date binary which is called which does not have the `-d` operand? Perhaps another shell with an date buildin. Try to call the date command using it's absolute path.

Comment: Well, Check if there are different OS on the machines and also the crontab format or the shell you are using to execute this program perhaps.

Comment: @Lambert yea i tried it and it runs perfectry from terminal. i have told in the begining the script runs well on terminal only not working with cron

Comment: What I meant is that cron might use another shell which has a date command/function buildin. Try to use the absolute path to the date command you want to use to see it's effect.

Comment: I would start the script with a shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) as you tell it's a bash script.

Comment: @jlliagre of course i already put that in my script

Comment: @Lambert i add the ehich date in crontab to be excuted every minute and the resualt is the same the problem is this command `end_YYYYMMDDHH=date --utc +%Y%m%d%H%i%s -d "${start_YYYY}-${start_MM}-${start_DD} ${start_HH}:${start_II}:${start_SS} UTC +${flen} hours"`

Comment: What parameters are passed to the script when run on the command line and when run by cron?

Comment: @jlliagre `run_wrf.sh $(date --utc +\%Y\%m\%d00) $(date --utc +\%Y\%m\%d00) 72 ` he gets the start date but when he gets to this part to run the code cann't run it. it must shift the current date 72 hrs

Answer (score 2):

You have different path settings when run by cron, so always use absolute paths in cron scripts or services.

Comment: but i tried to run the echo $path from my crontab and it gave me the same PATH. and if it is how to tell crontab to use my main PATH?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution:

`end_YYYYMMDDHH=$(date --date="${start_YYYY}-${start_MM}-${start_DD} ${start_HH}:${start_II}:${start_SS} UTC +${flen} hours" -u "+%Y%m%d%H")`

it work properly but for some reason if you move this part: `-u "+%Y%m%d%H"` to the begining of the command it gave that error!

the very strange thing is the same command works on another machine!

Comment: Different implementations of the `date` utility will work differently. On Ubuntu, you're using GNU date, and AFAIK, this command should work with the most current implementation of GNU `date`. The GNU `date` manual states that the formatting string should be last on the command line.