# Command works in terminal, but not in crontab

Tags: linux, ssh, cron, tar

I'm testing to set up some backup.
I set up my crontab to run every minute.
I have a  disk that is mounted on machine2 that I will upload the backup to.
I'm compressing the content of folder `/home/user/important` to `important.tar.gz` and moving the tar.gz file to machine2's `/mnt/backup2` folder.

cron tab entry:

```
* * * * * tar -czvf /home/user/important/important.tar.gz /home/user/important && 
rsync -vzhe ssh /home/user/important/*.tar* machine2:/mnt/backup2
```

This will not run with crontab.

I'm running the same command in terminal.
Then it works:

```
/home/user/important/
/home/user/important/a.txt
/home/user/important/test.txt
/home/user/important/this.txt
/home/user/important/is.txt
/home/user/important/important.tar.gz
/home/user/important/important.txt
/home/user/important/test1/
important.tar.gz

sent 9.85K bytes  received 35 bytes  19.76K bytes/sec
total size is 9.75K  speedup is 0.99
```

And file is received on machine2 in the /mnt/backup2 folder.

Any suggestions why it doesn't work with crontab?
Im running Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you describe the symptoms of "doesn't work"?

Comment: Yes, the tar.gz files isent uploaded to machine2:/mnt/backup2   it is uploaded when i run the same command line outside crontab.

Comment: Are you running the cron job exery minute - it appears you are, did you check the /var/log/cron.log file, and how many tar.gz files are being transfered - it appears only one. Try using the full name of the file in "/home/user/important/*.tar*" and replace "rsync -vzhe ssh" with scp since you appear to be only transferring 1 file which steps on the existing file. Or maybe just add the rhost user id to the "machine2:/mnt/backup2" piece of the command.

Comment: Is there an actual newline in the crontab entry? Did you check if cron is running (`systemctl status cron`)?

Comment: @Freddy I created a newline when editing the original wall of text. There wasn't any originally, but it was essentially unreadable.

Comment: There are two parts. Does cron create the tar file? What happens when you modify the crontab entry and only create the tar file? And only the rsync? Another point: This is done once a minute. What happens when you run it every five minutes?

Comment: General recommendation: Use full path names in cron jobs. So try again with `/bin/tar` and `/bin/rsync`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shell script work on terminal, not when it has run by cronjob](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346573/shell-script-work-on-terminal-not-when-it-has-run-by-cronjob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what's the real problem here, but here a couples things you could try:

- Put this one-liner in a script, `chmod -x` it and use this in the crontab

This will allow you more control over whatever is happening (eg: `set -x`, etc).

- Enable debugging output to see what is causing your crontab entry to not work as expected:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -x
```

or if you're using `sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/sh -x
```

or just use `set -x` instead.

I'm guessing it might be a problem of permissions or shell globing, but if it doesn't get solved by being in a script, you should do this:

```bsh
script.sh &> script.log
```

So you can clearly see what and how something is failing when being run as a cronjob...

- Check if there any entry in `crontab`

This one is obvious, but since some may use the `crontab` file instead of doing adding it directly through the `crontab`:

```bsh
echo "job entry" | crontab -
```

or the "normal" way, but require text editor to be opened, and the user copy pasting/typing their job/crontab entry manually...:

```bsh
crontab
```

or if you prefer a method that prevent duplicated entry:

```bsh
cronadd() {
if crontab -l | grep -wq -- "$@"; then
    :
else
    (crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "$@") | crontab -
fi
}
```

And you could use it like so:

```bsh
cronadd "job entry here"
```

It should prevent adding duplicate job and you can make sure it's actually added...
Always check with `crontab -l` though.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the good replies.
I tried everything until:

"I'm guessing it might be a problem of permissions or shell globing, but if it doesn't get solved by being in a script, you should do this:
script.sh &> script.log"

The problem was with permissions.
I ran crontab with Sudo, this made some problems.
When I added the command to a crontab ran as the user it worked.

Comment: How? How you run as the user? Can you give more details?